# Mutate (or Edit) Neo4j Data/Relationships from UI

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, graphql, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

While there are a number of tools and technologies to visualize `Neo4j` data, I couldn't find one that permits mutating attributes, or something as simple as renaming a node (`queue` or `topic`, it's `relationship` connector) and the likes.

I have exposed the `Neo4j` graph data, via the `Spring Data Neo4j` project. I'm considering to leverage the visualization via `d3.js` on a React (or any JavaScript framework/library) app. This [excellent tutorial](https://medium.com/neo4j/create-a-data-marvel-develop-a-full-stack-application-with-spring-and-neo4j-part-1-350f0f7e6609) provides a good (similar) reference to what I've been building on a custom graph-db data.

**Are there any libraries (or frameworks, projects) that exist which enable customizing, editing or mutating `Neo4j` data from a web-based UI?**

PS. I have explored [Graphileon](https://graphileon.com/), it's supposed to work as a stand-alone app, and it's not free :)

Answer (score 0):

Your statement that Graphileon is not "supposed to work as a stand-alone app" is not correct. Graphileon is also available as a server product. The desktop version is the free Personal Edition. It is available as native MacOS, Windows or Linux app , and you can run the UI also in your browser from localhost:3000